# Convert a vector of integers into a single number

Tags: r

Does anyone know a way to turn a vector of integers into a single number in R, for example:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3)
> x <- compress(x)
> x
[1] 123
```

Where `compress()` would be some sort of function to do so.
I would like the value `x` to be a single number so I can multiply it by an encryption key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
x = 1:3
as.numeric(paste(x, collapse = ""))
# 123
```

Comment: You're welcome. There's a R package called 'digest', maybe you want to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

When we write a number 123 that's the same as

```
1*10^2 + 2*10^1 + 3*10^0
```

so you can also do

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
sum(x * 10^((length(x)-1):0))
# [1] 123
```